# Magento - head JS

Tags: javascript, templates, magento, magento-1.9

I'm using `magento 1.9.2.4` and I have a small question:

In between the `<head></head>` i have the CSS files and the js files but there is also a piece of js code, something like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <titlte>Title</title>
    <link href="...">

    <!-- This is the thing that i'm trying to get access to -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //some js code here
    </script>
```

How/where is that code stored?(I have to modify it but i can't find it :|)

Answer (score 0):

app\design\frontend\base\default\template\page\html\head.phtml

all after the link tags.